Geometry Node Window co-ordinates for vertical content
I have a test project that outputs Window co-ordinates from Geometry Nodes (so a texture can be projected onto a material from a camera + alternate angle views can be rendered)
How to get the "Window Texture coordinates" in Geometry nodes?
This thread has a solution that works for Horizontal aspect ratios. When it is set vertical, the ratio correction works but the image zooms outside the bounds. Is there a method that works with horizontal and vertical aspect ratios?
Example below, the Pink box should be flush with the camera boundaries (works as intended with horizontal aspects)


Fixed, if the divide result is larger than 1, the image is downscaled the proportionate amount. Added nodes are highlighted in blue for anyone else in the same boat!

